# Java Freemarker templating engine access only custom annotated methods?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, templates, freemarker

During encapsulation of view variables to a POJO class and supplying it to the template processor, is it possible to limit the methods that can be invoked by the templating engine with a custom annotation? Limiting the visibility via private method is not possible because of inheritance.

I am using FreeMarker with Spring MVC.

**The template processor receives the POJO class from the controller:**

```
model.addAttribute("view", new SamplePOJO(this));
```

**The SamplePOJO class:**

```
public final class SamplePOJO extends View
{
    public SamplePOJO(MasterController<?> _inject)
    {
        super(_inject);
    }

    @CustomAnnotationOnValidMethods
    public String getValid_value()
    {
        return "valid call";
    }

    @Override
    public String getInvalid_value()
    {
        return "invalid call";
    }
}
```

**The template:**

```
<p>Valid invocation: ${view.valid_value}</p>
<p>Also valid but I want this to be impossible: ${view.invalid_value}</p>
```

Comment: How about limiting the visibility via `protected` methods? Or package-private methods?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `DefaultObjectWrapper` (or any other `BeansWrapper` subclass) has a `methodAppearanceFineTuner` setting (https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/beans/MethodAppearanceFineTuner.html). In your `MethodApperanceFineTuner` implementation you can hide a method by calling `MethodAppearanceDecision.setExposeMethodAs(null)`. 
You can inject your `MethodApperanceFineTuner` object where you configure FreeMarker, like, you create a `DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder`, call its `setMethodAppearanceFinteTuner(MethodAppearanceFinteTuner)` method, then `build()`, and pass the result to `Configuration.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper)`.